# How to create loosely coupled services in MVC architecture?

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, mvvm, architecture

I've tried to Google a lot but could not get an answer.

I'm building an MVC app and I have a question which bothering my mind. I would like to create a loosely coupled (as much as possible) services.
Let's assume in a method in a controller I want to use 3 different services (Services A,B,C).

Assuming service C needs service A and service B returned values in order to work, are you actually putting all that "calls logic" in the controller? In a different layer perhaps? If so, which layer is the ideal one?

Attaching some code to better explain my question.

```
function evaluateStatus(a, b){
   try {
   const aResult = this.aService.getSomething();
   const bReulst = this.bService.getSomething();

   if(aResult === "SOME VALUE" && bResult <= 50){
      const cResult = this.cService.doSomething(aResult); 
   }
   } catch(e) { 

   }

   return something;

}
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

A controller can invoke multiple services to obtain data to pass it to view/client. There is no point in having another layer for this. The controller contains the logic of the site and the glued between models/services and views/clients.

But if you have common business logic that is used across multiple places then you can take them out to a class/function where it can be reused.